# Как обрезать строку по определённый последний символ через Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка вида:

```
<a class="link" href="http://site.ru/tovary_dlya_doma/some_text_3223121314">link</a>
```

Как обрезать её таким образом, чтобы в переменной остался только ID (цифры в конце)? Этот айдишник потом будет подставляться в другую строку для ajax запроса.

Гуглил, но везде показывают примеры разделения строки на основе одного символа. Здесь же нужно обрезать по последнее нижнее подчеркивание. Нижних подчёркиваний может быть разное количество.

Как реализовать без регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, нашел ответ.

```
$('.link').each(function(){
    var href = String($(this).attr('href'));
    href = href.split('_').pop();
    console.log(href);
});
```

`.pop();` возвращает последний элемент из разбитых строк.

Comment: пометьте как решенное )

Comment: Не постесняюсь спросить, как? Не могу найти.

Comment: Галочка слева от этого ответа

Comment: @xaja Возможность принять свой ответ будет доступна только [по прошествию 48 часов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373/).